# Fastify idiom for responding with XML?

Tags: fastify

My Fastify app has a bunch of routes that respond with XML like so:

```js
await reply.type("application/xml").send(someObject.toXmlString());
```

This line is repeated for every route. Is there a Fastify idiom I could use to make this more DRY?

Comment: I'm wondering if there's a way I could just return `someObject` and have a lifecycle hook take care of the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many options here:

### Add a decorator:

```js
app.decorateReply('sendXml', function (payload) {
  return this.type('application/xml').send(payload.toXmlString());
});

app.get('/', async (request, reply) => {
  return reply.sendXml(xmlObj);
});
```

### preHandler hook

It sets default behaviour:

```js
app.addHook('preHandler', async function hook (request, reply) {
  reply
    .type('application/xml') //
    .serializer((data) => {
      return data.toXmlString();
    });
});

app.get('/', async (request, reply) => {
  return xmlObj;
});
```

### setReplySerializer

Setting the server's [`setReplySerializer`](https://fastify.dev/docs/latest/Reference/Server/#setreplyserializer).

```js
app.register(async function plugin (app, opts) {
  // all the routes in this `plugin`'s context will run the
  // following serializer
  app.setReplySerializer(function (payload, statusCode) {
    return payload.toXmlString();
  });

  app.get('/', async (request, reply) => {
    reply.type('application/xml');
    return reply.send(xmlObj);
  });
});
```

### preSerialization hook

Here I found a bug: https://github.com/fastify/fastify/issues/5282

```js
const app = require('fastify')({ logger: true });

app.addHook('preSerialization', (request, reply, payload, done) => {
  if (reply.getHeader('content-type') === 'application/xml') {
    done(null, payload.toXmlString());
  } else {
    done(null, payload);
  }
});

app.get('/', async (request, reply) => {
  reply.type('application/xml');

  return xmlObj
});

app.inject('/');
```